# Reference for the relation of the Casimir element to the Laplace Beltrami operator

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, laplacian

Wikipedia says,

"If $G$ is a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak {g}$, the choice of an invariant bilinear form on $\mathfrak {g}$ corresponds to a choice of bi-invariant Riemannian metric on  $G$. Then under the identification of the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak {g}$ with the left invariant differential operators on $G$, the Casimir element of the bilinear form on $\mathfrak {g}$ maps to the Laplacian of $G$ (with respect to the corresponding bi-invariant metric)."

Actually, a stronger claim is true for homogeneous spaces (and not only for the Lie group itself).

Do you have a reference to this claim, or even better, to a version of a stronger claim regarding homogeneous spaces?

Comment: I suspect that this is, essentially, the familiar claim that the Laplacian on $\mathbb R^n$ is the "only" differential operator that commutes with rototranslations. (The quotes are due to the fact that polynomials in the Laplacian also satisfy the property). Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find these [notes by Paul Garrett](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/lie/) helpful.